# Android Studio version 3.5 Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-studio-3.5

Hello ı want to use navigation drawer in android studio using kotlin. I am looking some documents and videos but before 2018 documents, system use onNavigationItemSelected method. But ı cannot see that method in android studio version 3.5. So, i cannot pass between fragments.

This is my mainactivity prepared by android studio:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: The new Navigation Drawer template uses the Navigation framework, which handles the actual `Activity` and `Fragment` navigations for you. That's what the `NavController` and `NavigationUI` stuff is. There is a way to pass `Fragment` arguments with that, but if you really don't want it, you can remove all of the Navigation code, and implement the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` yourself.

Comment: So, without remove navigation code, how am i gonna add new fragments ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you mean, how to transact new `Fragment` instances at runtime, the Navigation framework will do it for you. If, instead, you mean, how to integrate new `Fragment` classes and destinations into the existing setup, well then you'll just have to learn how to configure the Navigation framework.

Answer (score 3):

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull
            NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "nav_gallery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "nav_slideshow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_tools) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "nav_tools", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_share) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "nav_share", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_send) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "nav_send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (destination.getId() == R.id.logout) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "logout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done transaction like this.

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, menuFragment).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        //profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Profile");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, profileFragment).commit();
    }

    else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        showDialogg("Do you want to Logout?", 2, "Logout");
        return true;
    }
    try {
       // ft.commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```